# Polymer 1.0 add other polymer elements inside

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, web-component

Hello what is the difference of doing adding a child polymer element like this:

```
<dom-module id="app-element">
    <template>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
        <test-element></test-element>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: "app-element"
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
<app-element></app-element>
```

This works just fine.
The effect of adding html code (including other polymer elements) inside the app-element tag

```
<app-element>some html here</app-element>
```

like this:

```
 <dom-module id="app-element">
    <template>
        <h1>Hello</h1>

    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: "app-element"
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
<app-element>
    <test-element></test-element>
</app-element>
```

This ignores the test-element code. So in which cases can I add html code inside a polymer element? When will it be ignored? What would be the case where you want to add polymer elements inside other polymer elements inside the html code like this:

```
<app-element>
    <test-element></test-element>
</app-element>
```

?? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first case you are using **local dom**, in the second **light dom**.
In local dom, the custom element that contains it is responsible for the content (in this case app-element). So the *creator* of the custom element decides the content of the local dom. In contrast, using light dom provides the *user* of the custom element with the option to specify the content. The creator of the custom element can specify where the light dom should go inside the custom element using the `<content></content>` tag.  So to make your second example work you would need something like this:

```
<dom-module id="app-element">
    <template>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
        <content></content>
    </template>
<script>
    Polymer({
        is: "app-element"
    });
</script>
</dom-module>
<app-element>
    <test-element></test-element>
</app-element>
```

An example use case for light dom is the [paper-dialog](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-dialog). Using light dom, the user of the dialog can decide the content of the dialog. For example, the specific buttons to use, the main content of the dialog, etc.
Have a look at [this page](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom.html) in the documentation for more information on local and light dom.